# Traceback (most recent call last): File "./odoo-bin", line 5, in <module>

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./odoo-bin", line 5, in 
>       import odoo
>     File "/opt/odoo/odoo/odoo/**init**.py", line 73, in 
>       import babel
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'babel'

Comment: What are you trying to do? With what software? What do you expect to happen? What is the question?

Comment: Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

In Odoo  should install first all requirements

Navigate to your project folder then try to run this command in terminal

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

If get any error while this command execution, resolve that errors then only Odoo server work.

Answer (score 0):

If you use multi version of python 
Check version: 
 `python --version`  
e.g For me: Python 3.7.7 
 `py -3.7 -m pip install -r requirements.txt`